# Cannot install a pod (HTTPS ERROR)

Tags: github, https, cocoapods

I'm trying to use the command pod install and always have that:

$ sudo pod install

> Analyzing dependencies
>
> [!] Pod::Executable pull
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': Could not resolve
>   host: github.com

What is the problem??

Comment: Looks like you aren't able to get to the Github repo. You should check if `git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` succeeds without any errors.

Comment: Can you try again? It looks like you just could not access github.com and if so, this would be localised to that event only and not need to stick around

Comment: Localised to a temporary outage or fetch of the repo

Answer (score 1):

This is a local problem with your setup. I had the same issue and resolved by doing this:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Then run you pod commands again an you should be ok.